# Https Connection failure via Proxy Server in Python

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, proxy, windows-server, exchangelib

I am trying to read and send emails (O365) using OAuth2. This code works fine on my local machine, but

when I am trying to deploy this in a server where there is a proxy to access the internet, I am getting the below error.

> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2d11ad74-bbf6-403f-32c7-6ff0e039a923/oauth2/v2.0/token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002507067C348>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

Below is my code I tried:

```
import settings
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account, DELEGATE, BASIC, \
    Configuration, NTLM, Message, Mailbox, FileAttachment, HTMLBody, FaultTolerance, IMPERSONATION
from exchangelib.protocol import BaseProtocol, NoVerifyHTTPAdapter
from exchangelib import OAuth2LegacyCredentials

credentials = OAuth2LegacyCredentials(
  client_id= settings.clientId, client_secret= settings.clientSecret,
  tenant_id=settings.tenentId,
  username=settings.eUserName, password=settings.ePassword
)
config = Configuration(server = 'smtp.office365.com', credentials=credentials)
account = Account(settings.eUserName, config=config, access_type=DELEGATE)

m = Message(
  account=account,
  subject='Any Subject OAth2 Authentication',
  body=HTMLBody('OAth2 Authentication'),
  to_recipients=map(lambda x: Mailbox(email_address=x), ['myEmail@gmail.com'])
)

for item in account.inbox.all()[:10]:
  print (item.sender.email_address)

m.send()
print('Email is being sent...')
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add setup proxy configuration. Here's how to do that in exchangelib:

https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#proxies-and-custom-tls-validation